# How can one set up a thread in C# to only execute when CPU is idle?

Tags: c#, windows-services, cpu-usage

I have a Windows Service in C#. I want a certain thread to perform specific actions, but only when the CPU is idle. Is there a way to do this in C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can let the OS handle it for you like this:

```
Thread thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting ThreadPriority to BelowNormal or less. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority.aspx).